# Load multiline xml data into Hive table from text file

Tags: hadoop, hive, newline, multiline

My table in MSSQL has schema like:  `(id bigint, xmldata xml, other bigint)`
I want to create the same Hive table as SQL table. By using Sqoop, I got raw data files on HDFS, like:

```
1  5678|<root><l1><l2><productid>1234</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>|1002020
2  5679|<root><l1><l2><productid>1239</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>|4213212
3  5680||112345
4  ....
8  5688|<root><l1><l2><productid>1248</productid><description>Just
9  to 
10 show
11 </description></l2></l1></root>|12391023
12 5689|<root><l1><l2><productid>1259</productid><description>Just to
13 show</description></l2></l1></root>|12391021
```

The first number 1,2,3 are line number. I use `|` to delimit the columns. As you can see, see some xml field cross multiple lines.

My question is: how to create a hive table and load this raw data?

I have read related questions on SO but no one is in my case.
I tried:
`CREATE TABLE test (id Bigint, xmldata String, other Bigint) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';`
`Load data inpath 'path/raw' into table test`

The Hive table is not correct, like:

```
5678    <root><l1><l2><productid>1234</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>   1002020
5679    <root><l1><l2><productid>1239</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>   4213212
5680        112345
5688    <root><l1><l2><productid>1248</productid><description>Just  NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    12391023    NULL
5689    <root><l1><l2><productid>1259</productid><description>Just to   NULL
NULL    12391021    NULL
```

Update:

Tried:
`CREATE TABLE ts_test (id String, xmldata String, other String) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "^([^\|]*)[\|]([^\|]*)[\|]([^\|]*)$",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s"
);`
`Load data inpath 'path/test.xml' into table ts_test;`

The output table is not correct, like:

```
5678    <root><l1><l2><productid>1234</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>   1002020
5679    <root><l1><l2><productid>1239</productid><description>Just to show</description></l2></l1></root>   4213212
5680        112345
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I don't know the constraints of the technology you are using, but I would try to construct a database query that outputs pure XML rather than this awful CSV/XML hybrid.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the advise. But even if I only use XML rather than "awful" CSV/XML hybrid, the multiline problem is still there.

Comment: In real XML, newlines are just part of the data and don't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom InputFormat. Rather than repeating it, take a look at
[Using FileFormat v Serde to read custom text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734193/using-fileformat-v-serde-to-read-custom-text-files)

Comment: I tried Serde as updated, but the output table is still not correct, any ideas?